# Wagmi write contract

Tags: wagmi, nextjs, rainbowkit, wagmi-hooks, wagmi-react

I have this code here

```
import React from 'react';
import { usePrepareContractWrite, useContractWrite } from 'wagmi';
import lottoABI from './lottoABI.json';
import { parseEther } from 'viem';

// Your component code here

function Write() {
const { config, error } = usePrepareContractWrite({
address: '0x3262c6f03F4003F1b4D6162F40bae8A71a101ef3',
abi: lottoABI, // Use the imported ABI JSON file
functionName: 'participate',
value:parseEther('0.01'),
args:['0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C']
})
const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite(config)
console.log(data)

return (
<>
<button disabled={!write || isLoading} onClick={() => write?.()}>
{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : isSuccess ? 'Success!' : 'Bought'}

{error && (
An error occurred preparing the transaction: {error.message}

)}
</>
);
}
export default Write;
```

this function is suppsed to call a function on a smart contract with ETH value and an referral address

but when i run this in my nextjs project i see this error
ContractFunctionExecutionError: HTTP request failed.

URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org
Request body: {"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C","data":"0xb91038c7000000000000000000000000293bcb20584a2e0e6d1b559e25783311ec29121c","to":"0x3262c6f03F4003F1b4D6162F40bae8A71a101ef3"},"latest"]}

Raw Call Arguments:
from: 0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C
to: 0x3262c6f03F4003F1b4D6162F40bae8A71a101ef3
data: 0xb91038c7000000000000000000000000293bcb20584a2e0e6d1b559e25783311ec29121c

Contract Call:
address: 0x3262c6f03F4003F1b4D6162F40bae8A71a101ef3
function: participate(address _referrer)
args: (0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C)
sender: 0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C

Docs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/simulateContract.html
Details: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

and i also get this error
An error occurred preparing the transaction: Execution reverted for an unknown reason. Raw Call Arguments: from: 0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C to: 0x3262c6f03F4003F1b4D6162F40bae8A71a101ef3 value: 0.01 SEP data: 0xb91038c7000000000000000000000000293bcb20584a2e0e6d1b559e25783311ec29121c Contract Call: address: 0x3262c6f03F4003F1b4D6162F40bae8A71a101ef3 function: participate(address _referrer) args: (0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C) sender: 0x293Bcb20584a2e0E6d1b559E25783311ec29121C Docs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/simulateContract.html Details: execution reverted Version: viem@0.3.39

im on sepolia testnet
does anyone know what i need to do to fix this?

Looking at the console, it seems that my writeContract function is called every block, why is that?